# Как изменить файл выгрузки модуля яндекс маркет для бизнеса в 1с-битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, яндекс-маркет

Помогите пожалуйста очень нужно изменить код выгрузки для яндекс маркета, добавить в него условие.
нужно поправить файл выгрузки xml в зависимости от свойства инфоблока Наличие:

1. Если Наличие - (не установлено), то предложение не попадает в файл
2. Если Наличие под заказ

```html
<offer>

....

<delivery>false</delivery>

<pickup-options>

<option cost="0" days="21"/>

</pickup-options>

<pickup>true</pickup>

<store>false</store>

....

</offer>
```

3. Если наличие На заводе

```html
<offer>

....

<delivery>false</delivery>

<pickup-options>

<option cost="0" days="7"/>

</pickup-options>

<pickup>true</pickup>

<store>false</store>

....

</offer>
```

4. Если наличие в шоу-руме

```html
<offer>

....

<delivery>false</delivery>

<pickup-options>

<option cost="0" days="0-1"/>

</pickup-options>

<pickup>true</pickup>

<store>false</store>

....

</offer>
```

Пробовал вносить изменения в файл yandex_run.php, но изменения не работают, скорее всего потому что в выгрузке не используется этот файл
как я понял модуль связан вот с этой папкой /bitrix/modules/yandex.market/lib/export/ и изменения нужно вносить в какой-то файл из этой папки. есть файл vendormodel.php, но не могу понять где в нем происходит запись в выгрузку?

Answer (score 0):

используйте Единый модуль «Яндекс.Маркет для бизнеса»
https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/yandex.market/
Пример подготовки прайс‑листа в системе 1С‑Битрикс видео:
https://yandex.ru/support/market-cms/

Comment: Я его и использую, но мне нужно добавить в его код разные условия при формировании тега pickup